# Complex Circle progress bar in flutter

Tags: progress-bar, flutter-circularprogressindicator

[Progress bar sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytQPv.png)
How to create circle progress with animation which separate selected progress bar or unSelected progress bar with gap and custom round corner of progress bar also customize animation time according to user-need.